# Regex: Accept words and hyphen when between words

Tags: regex, python-3.x, dataframe

I'm trying to remove noise from my Dataframe in python using regex [^A-Z0-9] but it is also removing my certain cases.

**Example:**

```
BARACK-OBAMA 
JUAN\n\n$$ -- an\n\n---
```

**Should result in**

```
BARACK-OBAMA
JUAN
```

**but my regex returns**

```
BARACKOBAMA
JUAN
```

Therefore I want to save a case where it should not remove hyphen, if it occurs between two strings and remove it in all other cases.

Comment: I retitled the question; hope I captured your intent correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can special case the hyphen by adding it to your negated character class and then looking for a hyphen that is either not preceded or not followed by a upper-case character and removing it:

```
text = '''
BARACK-OBAMA 
JUAN\n\n$$ -- an\n\n---
'''
print(re.sub(r'[^A-Z0-9-]|(?<![A-Z])-|-(?![A-Z])', '', text))
```

Output

```
BARACK-OBAMA
JUAN
```

Note you will want to include `0-9` in the character classes in the lookarounds if you want to not replace a hyphen in (for example) `JOE10-FRED` i.e.

```
print(re.sub(r'[^A-Z0-9-]|(?<![A-Z0-9])-|-(?![A-Z0-9])', '', text))
```